# ssas cube: How is the data being pulled?

Tags: ssas, cube, fact-table

If there is single partition for a measure group, aggregation designed 0%, partition table being used as an empty table (a template),
how does the cube browser still show data for the measure in that measure group.

FYI: The partitions are generally created monthwise like vw_fact_patronrevenue_2007_1, vw_fact_patronrevenue_2007_2 and so forth, along with a template (vw_fact_patronrevenue_template) which contains no data.

But, for the particular measure I had issues about, there is just one partition and the partition table/view is a template.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out...thas not possible. The wording "Template" is wrong, because for other measure group partitions, the templates have "where 1=2" clause. But, the template I am talking about does not have that clause. The assumption of having "where" clause in a template got me wrong.